# Read the full out of office (a.k.a. vacation) notice in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I write an email to my colleagues and they have a vacation notice set, an line above the recipient address appears showing the notice. However, in 11 out of 10 cases this message is longer than one line and Outlook truncates it to whatever it believes sensible.

How can I read the full vacation notice without sending an email and waiting for the reply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put your mouse on the message, an hover box with the full message should appear.

[image: Mouse Over]

Comment: Looks like I wasn't patient enough. The mouse has to sit still for several seconds but then it appears.

Comment: How can this be read by the REST API if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if there is multiple recipients with automatic replies, if you look at the far right of the line with the 'notice', you will see a little down carrot.  Click that and it will expand to see all.  No hovering needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is amazing for my use case: checking out-of-office dates for a mailing list where there are usually multiple out-of-office messages and would have to then check one by one.